# Launchctl:Dubious permissions on file: Problem Installing Jenkins

Tags: install, permission, plist

I'm trying to install Jenkins on 10.6.8 and part of this requires that modify the plist launch daemon.  org.jenkins-ci.plist   which is owned by root.  I was using admin and I gave admin permission to write this file. I used this permission to make the admin the jenkins user and set the home directory to be the admin user directory.  However now I cannot run the launch daemon.

```
launchctl: Dubious permissions on file (skipping)
```

Now I realize this is due to a security issue with having given myself this permission.  The plist now has my admin user as the user for jenkins.  Should I now just remove the write privileges and all is good (admin can now be the jenkins user) or not?

Update: I did `sudo chown root org.jenkins-ci.plist` and it still feels things are dubious.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in /Library/LaunchDaemons, which I assume you are for a system daemon, and want the files to go back to default:

```
sudo chown root:wheel org.jenkins-ci.plist
sudo chmod 644 org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

The plist will register on reboot, or you can load it like this:

```
sudo launchctl load org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

You can check the status like this:

```
sudo launchctl list <<Job Name>>
```

Note that jobname is not the same as file name. Inside the plist you'll see a Label. That's the name:

```
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>DataScrub</string>
```

In my example the name is DataScrub, so would be:

```
sudo launchctl list DataScrub
```

Comment: Added some launchctl info for you.